# How to pass a backcolor in panels with Drag and Drop in C#

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

we have this schoolproject where we need te program Mastermind in C#. We visualize the colors with panels. So we have the row AvaibleColors at the top, and x-number of rows panels to guess the code. Where X is the number of turns.

We need to implent an Drag and Drop event where the user drags one of the avaible colors to a panel in the guessing row. For instance, the user clicks and drags a Red color to a panel in the row, then that panel's backcolor needs to change to red.

This is what i have so far:

```
#region CreatePanels
    public void CreatePanelArrayColors(int aantalKleuren) 
    {
        pa = new Panel[aantalKleuren];
        for (int i = 0; i < pa.Length; i++) {
            pa[i] = new Panel();
            pa[i].Width = 40;
            pa[i].Height = 40;
            pa[i].Top = 18;
            pa[i].Left = 6 + i * 46;
            pa[i].Tag = i;

            pa[i].MouseDown += paAC_MouseDown;


            kleurenToewijzen(pa, (int)pa[i].Tag, i);
            grpAvailColors.Controls.Add(pa[i]);
        }
    }

    public void CreatePanelGuess(int nmbrColorsToGuess)
    {
        pa = new Panel[nmbrColorsToGuess];
        for (rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < g.Turns; rowNumber++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < pa.Length; j++)
            {

                pa[j] = new Panel();
                pa[j].Width = 30;
                pa[j].Height = 30;
                pa[j].Top = (rowNumber * 30 + rowNumber * 3) + 3;
                pa[j].Left = 3 + j * 36;
                pa[j].BackColor = Color.LightGray;

                pa[j].AllowDrop = true;
                pa[j].DragEnter += paTG_DragEnter;
                pa[j].DragDrop += paTG_DragDrop;

                ActieveTeRadenRij(pa, j, rowNumber);
                pnlColorsToGuess.Controls.Add(pa[j]);
            }

            for (int correctie = 0; correctie < pa.Length; correctie++)
            {

                pa[correctie] = new Panel();
                pa[correctie].Width = 10;
                pa[correctie].Height = 10;
                pa[correctie].Top = (rowNumber * 30 + rowNumber * 3) + 30 / 2 - 1;
                pa[correctie].Left = (3 + g.ColorsGuess * 36) + 10 + correctie * 18;
                pa[correctie].BackColor = Color.Gray;

                pa[correctie].AllowDrop = true;
                pa[correctie].DragEnter += paTG_DragEnter;
                pa[correctie].DragDrop += paTG_DragDrop;

                pnlColorsToGuess.Controls.Add(pa[correctie]);
            }
            //bt[0] = new Button();
            //bt[0].Top = (rowNumber * 50 + rowNumber * 3) + 50 / 2;
            //bt[0].Left = (3 + g.ColorsGuess * 56) + 10 + g.ColorsGuess * 18 + 10;

            //pnlColorsToGuess.Controls.Add(bt[0]);
        }
        CreateTryButton();
    }

    #region DragAndDrop
    private void paTG_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Panel)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Panel))).Parent = (Panel)sender;
    }
    private void paTG_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
    private void paAC_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Panel pnl = sender as Panel;
        pnl.DoDragDrop(pnl, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
    #endregion
```

The problem is that when we drag a panel the a row, this panel disappears and the color does not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do something like that:

```
private void paTG_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Color));

    if(data != null)
        ((Panel)sender).BackColor = (Color)data;
}
private void paAC_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Panel pnl = sender as Panel;
    if(pnl != null)
        pnl.DoDragDrop(pnl.BackColor, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

The differences in comparison to your code are:

- I use `BackColor` property of the `Panel` class in `paTG_DragDrop` method in order to change its color.
- I use `Color` as data to drag.
- I assume that `BackColor` property of source panels is populated with appropriate colors. If you have a different approach, it can be easily changed.